# multidexing with gradle 1.5.0 in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Following are entries in my app build.gradle script

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.srt.ujn.jsonparsing"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
```

I have also copied android-support-multidex.jar to app lib folder and used it as a library.

Following error is generated while running the app
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class

As i had learned somewhere that u need not add dependencies explicitly so i removed the following lines

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
```

But it did not worked and same error was generated.
Can someone help, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you clean the build after removing the extra compile dependencies?

Comment: This can also happen if one of the "jar"s in your "libs" directory has a reference to multidex (for some weird reason...)

Comment: Yes i am able to clean and rebuild project successfully, problem occurs only when i try to run the app